# Getting the value in a field in the json object that comes in tabular form with django

Tags: python, json, django, for-loop

I get the data from the postgresql table as json as follows. But for example in the data coming in json; I want to display the data in the "symbol" field in the "for" loop. How can I do that ?

So more than one data is coming and I want to print it on the screen one by one.

```
[
{"model": "cryptoinfo.cryptoinfo", 
"pk": 4, 
"fields": 
{"createdDate": "2020-10-08T20:49:16.622Z", "user": 2, "created_userKey": "25301ba6-1ba9-4b46-801e-32fc51cb0bdc", "customerKey": "61754ecf-39d3-47e0-a089-7109a07aca63", "status": true, "side": "BUY", "type": "1", "symbol": "NEOUSDT", "quantity": "1", "reversePosition": "1", "stopMarketActive": "1", "shortStopPercentage": "1", "longStopPercentage": "1", "takeProfit": "1", "addPosition": "1", "takeProfitPercentage": "1", "longTakeProfitPercentage": "1", "shortTakeProfitPercentage": "1", "groupCode": "1453", "apiKey": "2200", "secretKey": "0022"}}, 

{"model": "cryptoinfo.cryptoinfo", 
"pk": 7, 
"fields": {"createdDate": "2020-10-08T20:51:16.860Z", "user": 1, "created_userKey": "2f35f875-7ef6-4f17-b41e-9c192ff8d5df", "customerKey": "b1c8cee3-c703-4d27-ae74-ad61854f3539", "status": true, "side": "BUY", "type": "1", "symbol": "NEOUSDT", "quantity": "1", "reversePosition": "1", "stopMarketActive": "1", "shortStopPercentage": "1", "longStopPercentage": "1", "takeProfit": "1", "addPosition": "1", "takeProfitPercentage": "1", "longTakeProfitPercentage": "1", "shortTakeProfitPercentage": "1", "groupCode": "1453", "apiKey": "0011", "secretKey": "1100"}}

]


def webhook(request):
    json_body = json.loads(request.body)

    queryset = CryptoInfo.objects.filter(status=True, symbol=json_body['symbol'], side=json_body['side'])
    data = serializers.serialize('json', queryset)
    print(data['symbol'])
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import json

def webhook(request):
  ...
  data = serializers.serialize('json', queryset)
  for crypto_info in json.loads(data):
    print(crypto_info['fields']['symbol'])
```

Comment: KeyError: 'symbol',  buddy gave "key" error.
When I type crypto_info ['fields'] it fetches all fields. But when I type symbol, I get an error.